# What are the properties/features of JQuery alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I'm currently uses JQuery alerts using `<script src="js/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` this plugin. The alerts are very attractive using this, I want to know more about it i.e. its features or properties or attributes etc. I coded following alert:

```
jAlert("Please enter <font color='red'>name</font>");
jAlert("Please enter valid <b>name</b>");
```

Comment: Why don't you read its documentation?

Comment: @Felix Kling I'm searching for this but can you please let me related links?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery.alerts.js ... first hit.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't edit an older question and change it completely. This is really bad and invalidates all the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nice library.

You can find all you need about it on:
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

And here is some tutorial you can check:
http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-alert-how-to-use-alert-box-in-jquery-with-code-and-running-example/

Regards